# Jenkins JUnit Report multiple failures\errors

Tags: java, jenkins, junit4

I build a function that create JUnit report format xml that Jenkins can read.
my problem is that when I report 2 or more failures \ errors, Jenkins shows just the first on. 
Also I tried to gather all error to one detailed error but jenkins show it not clear.

my xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="2" hostName="name" name="Reporter" tests="1" time="202.053" timeStamp="Sun Jul 15 07:38:13 UTC 2018">
<testcase classname="bla" name="fail1" time="105.704">
<failure message="failure1" type="">trace...</failure>
<failure message="failure2" type="">trace2...</failure>
</testcase>
</testsuite>
```

jenkins shows he first only.

On other side if I put all failures in one node looks like this (I build it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><testsuite errors="0" failures="2" hostName="name" name="Reporter" tests="1" time="202.053" timeStamp="Sun Jul 15 07:38:13 UTC 2018">
<testcase classname="bla" name="fail1" time="105.704">
<failure message=
"failure1
failure2
failure3
...
.."

type="">trace...</failure>
</testcase>
</testsuite>
```

all failures shown in on line without new line char.

can someone assist if there is a way to do it correctly?

Thanks,

Hezi

Comment: In Junit, one test case can only produce one failure.

Comment: Can you post the jenkins output?

Comment: Error Message
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- (1)07:40:48: Failure 1 (2)07:40:48: Failure 2 (3)07:40:48: Failure 2 (4)07:40:48: Failure 2, the error seperated with new line but it appears like this

Comment: Use the xunit or junit plugin.

Comment: I am using junit plugin. The problem happens there

Comment: Any solution on this? Having Codeception with PHPUnit creating junit.xml with two  failures for one test case as well. I am using xunit.